# How can I remove the unintended line in Unity generated by tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded and imported the free tilemap esset but there are [vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxAlY.png) in the Game screen. The error didn't occur in the Scene screen and even when I had tried building it the game runned without any problem. So, it seems not to be deadly error but it can disturb me while making and testing the game.

I checked the Pixel Per Unit, Filter Mode, and Compression of this tilemap and they were correctly set. I disabled anti-aliasing as well (It worked partially, removing horizontal lines).

Answer (score 0):

While this *should* resolve the artefact/tearing issue you’re seeing, using a Sprite Atlas is also a good habit to get into even if you’re not seeing the issue anyway.

The Sprite Atlas packs the sprites in such a way that they have a little padding that can stop the texture bleeds that can sometimes cause unwanted horizontal and vertical lines to appear between sprite tiles.

The Sprite Atlas workflow can be read in detail [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteAtlasWorkflow.html).

From that documentation, the 3 basic steps are:

1. Create a Sprite Atlas Asset.
   To create the Sprite Atlas Asset, go to Assets > Create > 2D > Sprite Atlas. Unity creates the Sprite Atlas in the Asset folder, with the file extension * .spriteatlas.
2. Select a list of Objects for Packing into the Sprite Atlas. 
   [image]
   The Objects for Packing list displays the currently selected items that are in the Sprite Atlas. You can place Texture2D and Sprite Assets in this list. Drag and drop a folder directly onto the list to automatically add all valid content within the folder to the list (only the folder appears on the list).
3. Enable Include in build on Sprite Atlases to include them with the project. 
   [image]